# How to add individual labels to points on a line graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am wanting to add labels pointing out the year of the 3 highest, and 3 lowest temperatures on a line graph showing changes in average temperature. I can't figure out how to do so for just those 6 points, instead of every point... Any help?

```
#load data up 
library(readxl)
TempData <- read_excel("R Data/TempData.xlsx")
View(TempData)

#initiliase relevant packages #ggplot2 for creating data visulation and viridis to allow for colour gradients
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)

#plot line graph
g1 <- ggplot(TempData, aes(x = Year, y = GAT, color = GAT)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.5)  +
  geom_smooth(method=loess, se=TRUE, col = "black") +
  scale_colour_gradient2(low = "green", mid = "yellow" , high = "red", midpoint=median(TempData$GAT)) +
  labs(title = "Global Average Temperature", subtitle = "From 1850 to 2018") +
  xlab("Year") +  ylab ("Average Temperature") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", hjust = 0.5, size = 16)) +
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(face = "italic", hjust = 0.5, size = 10, colour = "Orange")) +
  theme_light()

plot(g1)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, one way is to make a separate/smaller data.frame, with only the observations of interest and then pass that as `data` to `geom_label(data = new_specific_df)`. If you want people to be able to re-create your plots/code it would be helpful if you added a link to "TempData.xlsx" perhaps as DropBox document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Nate suggested, a common approach is to feed a subset of your data into `geom_text`. You could define those before `ggplot2` or if it's simple, define those inline and feed into that layer's own `data` term. Here, I use `dplyr::top_n` to grab the top 3 and bottom 3 weights.

```
library(dplyr)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = hp, label = mpg)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.5)  +
  geom_smooth(method=loess, se=TRUE, col = "black") +
  scale_colour_gradient2(low = "green", mid = "yellow" , high = "red", 
                         midpoint=median(mtcars$hp))  +
  geom_text(data = mtcars %>% top_n(3, wt), 
            hjust = 1.5, color = "black", angle = 90) +
  geom_text(data = mtcars %>% top_n(-3, wt), 
            hjust = -0.5, color = "black", angle = 90) +
  theme_light()
```

We don't have your data so I took your code and applied it to the standard `mtcars` dataset. (Not a great aesthetic match but you get the idea...)

[image]

Comment: Thank you ever so much! This worked perfectly! A quick follow up question - how do I avoid overlap?

Comment: `ggrepel::geom_text_repel` is useful for that. `geom_text` also has a "checkoverlap" option to prevent overlapping labels from appearing.